# Spring Boot + MS SQL Server + Liquibase : Table creation error

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase with SQL Server and Spring Boot and my Boot application terminated with error

`The specified schema name "public" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it. [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE [public].[DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK] ([ID] [int] NOT NULL, [LOCKED] [bit] NOT NULL, [LOCKGRANTED] [datetime2](3) NULL, [LOCKEDBY] [nvarchar](255) NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]))]`.

I don't want liquibase to access my production DB and create tables.

So, I tried to override liquibase properties in my `application.yml`file like `liquibase.enabled: false`but its not working. I changed default schema value as well but still it is trying to create table in "public" schema. How to stop creating tables and make application start.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `application.yml`, then you must follow yaml syntax:

```
liquibase.enabled: false
```

Comment: Its typo error, i used yaml syntax but liquibase is not disabled.